# Has anyone successfully cross compiled GHC 7.8.3 for Raspberry pi on a Mac?

Tags: macos, haskell, raspberry-pi, ghc

Has anyone successfully cross compiled GHC 7.8.3 for raspberry pi on a Mac?
My build keeps failing with the following error.

ld: archive has no table of contents file '/Volumes/Media/RaspberryPi/ghc-7.8.3/libraries/terminfo/dist-boot/build/libHSterminfo-0.4.0.0.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [utils/ghc-pkg/dist/build/tmp/ghc-pkg] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Why don't you compile directly on your Raspberry?
I recently successfully compiled GHC7.8.3 on an ARM device...
http://arnon.dk/ive-managed-to-compile-ghc-7-8-3-on-an-nvidia-tegra-jetson-k1/

Comment: How long did that take?

Comment: It took me three days to get it right. I think the actual compilation took about 4 hours.

Comment: Was it on a raspberry pi? I read somewhere that it took someone a week to compile it.

Comment: No, it was on an Nvidia Tegra (in the link I posted).